# plesk when upgrading php, will this break everything?

Tags: php, centos, server, vps, plesk

I'm running a VPS with centOS, plesk 12 and PHP5.3. I'm looking to upgrade to a more recent version of php but without taking down all my sites running on that server.

I've tried through the plesk GUI and got to this point which is ambiguous to what it will do. Is this the way to do it or will it delete my version of php 5 and replace it with something unknown?

Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have CentOS6 or 7 and latest Plesk microupdates installed. After that you will be able to safely use Multiple PHP feature in Plesk - http://kb.odin.com/125146

Comment: ah, ok - currrently running 5.8

Comment: changed to a new host